# Hibernate initializes one-to-many set with null when referenced non-foreign key column is null

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, spring-data-jpa

I have a bidirectional one-to-many relation between EntityA and EntityB. The relation is not based on a foreign key, instead entities need to be linked with a unique `linking_field` in database. Relevant mappings:

EntityA:

```
@Id
private Long id;

@OneToMany(mappedBy = "entityA")
private Set<EntityB> children = new HashSet<>();

@Column(name = "linking_field")
private String linkingField;
```

EntityB:

```
@ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
@JoinColumn(name = "entity_a_id", referencedColumnName = "linking_field", nullable = false)
private EntityA entityA;
```

Now, let's imagine a situation where EntityB's table is empty. The problem is that when I try to fetch entityA, which has `null` value in `linking_field` column, with Spring Data repository method that explicitly `JOIN FETCH`es `children` field, the `children` field is initialized with `null`. However, it's not the case when the `linking_field` is set - then Hibernate assigns an empty `PersistentSet` to `children`, which is a desired behavior for me. Is there any way I can overcome that?

EntityA has `linkingField == null`:

```
EntityA entityA = entityARepository.findByIdWithChildren(entityAId);
entityA.getChildren(); // null
```

EntityA has `linkingField != null`:

```
EntityA entityA = entityARepository.findByIdWithChildren(entityAId);
entityA.getChildren(); // empty Set -> desirable
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What is your problem ?

Comment: My problem is that Hibernate assigns null to persistent collection instead of an empty collection under circumstances mentioned above

Comment: Accualy both behavior is fine and as expected. If linkingField is null then it can't do search in for children that's why result is null.

Comment: If that's expected behavior, then I'm confused, since it can easily lead to null pointer exceptions. To my mind Hibernate should never introduce null references for collections. Do you know by any chance if that behavior is documented anywhere?

Comment: You can check null  in like getter method or where you use. And in a document every detail case may not be included .

Comment: I would need to have something like getChildren() { if children == null then children = new HashSet<>() return children } then, but it's not a solution due to orphan removal I have specified in @OneToMany. Hibernate would throw an exception.

Comment: I don't see a reason why they are overriding that collection with null. I guess I need to debug Hibernate code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently, it's how Hibernate works unfortunately. I've debugged the code and this is a relevant piece from Hibernate's `CollectionType` class:

```
private Object resolveKey(Serializable key, SharedSessionContractImplementor session, Object owner, Boolean overridingEager) {
    // if (key==null) throw new AssertionFailure("owner identifier unknown when re-assembling
    // collection reference");
    return key == null ? null : // TODO: can this case really occur??
        getCollection( key, session, owner, overridingEager );
}
```

In my case the `key` parameter is null, so it turns out that they simple overwrite the whole collection with null.